# How to test if a directory is a python module path?

Tags: python

In order to test if a directory `path` if a python module path (i.e. contains a file named `__init__.py`) one can do something like

```
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, '__init__.py'))
```

I wonder if there is a special function call to do that?

Comment: Note that that is not a future-proof solution: [New in Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the  [imp.find_module(name[, path])](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) to test if a particular module is present in a certain path

How to use

```
import imp
fname, pathname, description = imp.find_module("__test__.py", path)
if not fname:
    #File is not present
else:
    #File is present
    fname.close()
```

**Form the documentation**

> If search is successful, the return value is a 3-element tuple (file,
>   pathname, description): ..... If the module does not live in a file,
>   the returned file is None, pathname is the empty string, and the
>   description tuple contains empty strings for its suffix and mode